# RHEL 8 + yum complained about dependencies in spite required dependencies exist

Tags: rhel, python, dnf

we have RHEL 8.4 and we try to install the following rpm

```
yum localinstall  ambari-agent-2.6.2.2-1.x86_64.rpm
Failed loading plugin "product-id": No module named 'subscription_manager.productid'
Failed loading plugin "subscription-manager": cannot import name 'injection'
Failed loading plugin "upload-profile": cannot import name 'packageprofilelib'
Last metadata expiration check: 0:22:37 ago on Mon 01 May 2023 03:16:36 PM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides rpm-python needed by ambari-agent-2.6.2.2-1.x86_64
  - nothing provides python >= 2.6 needed by ambari-agent-2.6.2.2-1.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

as we can see from above yum exception yum complain about

```
  - nothing provides python >= 2.6 needed by ambari-agent-2.6.2.2-1.x86_64
```

but in fact, we already installed python2 on this server as the follwing

```
python --version
Python 2.7.18

rpm -qa | grep python2
python2-pip-wheel-9.0.3-19.module+el8.6.0+13001+ad200bd9.noarch
python2-pip-9.0.3-19.module+el8.6.0+13001+ad200bd9.noarch
python2-setuptools-wheel-39.0.1-13.module+el8.4.0+9442+27d0e81c.noarch
python2-setuptools-39.0.1-13.module+el8.4.0+9442+27d0e81c.noarch
python2-2.7.18-11.module+el8.7.0+15681+7a92afba.x86_64
python2-libs-2.7.18-11.module+el8.7.0+15681+7a92afba.x86_64

alternatives --config python

There are 3 programs which provide 'python'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           /usr/libexec/no-python
   2           /usr/bin/python3
 + 3           /usr/bin/python2

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

**what I am missing here ?**

Comment: Is it possible that the ambari-agent was built for rhel 7? I think what you are missing is that it is looking for the `python` package and not the `python2` package. On RHEL7 the package would have been `python`, but on RHEL 8 they shifted to `python2` and `python3` I guess to make the install less ambiguous in the transition to python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambari 2.6.2 is not compatibile with rhel8, and issue ist that command `yum provides python` wont return any packages/rpms.

In theory you could create and install mock rpm that provides `python`
Then `ambari-agent` should install, but still **won't be functional**.

I'm assuming you need to install Ambari to add node to cluster, based on that your actual solutions are:

1. Install rhel7/centos7 and resolve driver issues (ie. to new network/hba card)
2. Create new cluster on rhel8 without Ambari from tar's and migrate
3. Wait, maybe Ambari 2.8 or 2.9 will have support for rhel8
4. Build your own Ambari with patches for rhel8

The most demanding, but also most revarding is option 4. To achieve that you'll need [Apache Bigtop](https://github.com/apache/bigtop/tree/master), some patches from [this repository](https://github.com/clemlabprojects/ambari), and about 5 months of your life.